# Table borders on main Blogger page messed up

Tags: css, blogger

When I make a post on a Blogger blog with a table in it, it appears OK.

When I goto the MAIN blogger landing page the ***SAME*** post shows up, but the table CSS in that post is ***slightly*** changed.

Example : [See Table 1 in this link](https://blog.theleapjournal.org/2021/03/how-large-is-payment-delays-problem-in.html), here is the screenshot :-

[image: Table on the post page]

this appears with BORDERS on the [main page](https://blog.theleapjournal.org/), here is the screenshot:-

[image: Table on the Main page]

Why is this ? Is there a dirty hack to prevent this ?

Also, when we add/delete some posts, the RIGHTMOST border on ALL cells in tables on the main page disappears.

Note : This missing right border issue also affects the Google search (on top) box's border as well.

Here are the screenshots :-
[image: Right border OK]

[image: Missing Right border]

Please notice how the right border for each cell is missing in the above.

It's, as if Blogger is perhaps, taking a cue from the first blog post and creating the CSS for the main page tables from that post, but I am not 100% sure.

Can someone please explain what is going on and if there are hacks to prevent the CSS of the tables in the posts on the main page from being different from the CSS of tables in the corresponding blog posts?

Comment: You have inline CSS defining border and padding rules for tables on your main page. That is why you see the aforementioned borders.

Comment: Dear nadz, I only created the "post" page, not the main page. I think the main page is being generated by Blogger "automagically" and when it is doing that it is applying inline CSS on it's own.  Do I understand correctly? Can you tell me how to "fix" the main page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize your theme to override the existing table styles with the following:

```
thead, tbody, th, td
{ 
    border: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Follow [this](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/176245?hl=en#zippy=%2Cuse-css) article to add custom CSS to your active theme.

Comment: Dear nadz, many thanks. I will try this out.

Comment: Dear nadz, when I did what you suggested it ***worked*** for the border around the  cells inside the table but *still* made a border around a table. I got rid of that using : `table { border : none !important ;}` in addition to what you suggested. I have a query : Is there not a way to do this on a per table basis instead of applying CSS to the ***entire*** blog ?